# Acceptable practice with creating objects that are mutually dependent on it's "container" class?

Tags: c++11

Say I have a class structure that could hold a group of objects, and that the objects that it was containing needed to have access to the container that itself is contained in.  Here is an example class structure of what I am talking about:

```
class Item;
class Container {
private:
    std::vector<Item*> items;
    ....
public:
    void add(Item *newItem) {
        items.push_back(newItem);
    }
    ....
}

class Item {
private:
    int data;
    Container* container;
    ....
public:
    Item(int data, Container* container) {
        this->data = data;
        this->container = container;
        if(container != nullptr) {
            container.add(this);
        }
    }
    ....
}
```

This would allow me to create an object easily like this:

```
Container contain;
new Item(1, &contain);
new Item(2, &contain);
new Item(3, &contain);
```

I could then easily access these objects through the container object, and this would by no means cause a memory leak by freely creating objects like this.

However, is this bad practice to create objects this way?  Also, instead of accessing the container directly through a pointer stored in the objects themselves, should I just pass the container as a function parameter for whenever it needs to be used?

Comment: How do you plan to clean up these objects?

Comment: This is a very-tightly coupled design, obviously.  That's...not great.  Your container can only work with item, and your item can only work with a container.  Assuming your item has any other functionality, and I assume it does...you're stuck using it in your container.  Aaand I think this is an odd way of creating the objects to boot.  If you're going to tightly-couple, I'd consider having the container do double-duty as a limited class factory, or having a separate one.  So like `contain.AddItem(1)`.  But at a guess (without knowing the high-level problem), I'd say it's still a bad design.

Comment: A design where neither class knows about the other is ideal (`vector<type>`), but difficult and possibly not as "friendly" to use as one might like.  The typical fallback is the container knowing about the type it contains.  A type knowing about a generic container (item knows about vector, for example) would also be normal.  Them knowing about each other is something I would make a best effort to avoid.

Comment: Another thing you could look at if the tightly-coupled design is truly useful for you is this `nested classes`:  http://www.icce.rug.nl/documents/cplusplus/cplusplus17.html

Comment: For what it's worth, Qt's `QObject` [ownership mechanism](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/objecttrees.html) works pretty much the way you show. Except that every `QObject` can be both a container and an item.